# Recomendations or information on adding biocides in furnace pan

Tags: plumbing, furnace, air-conditioning

I have heard that it is recommended to add some amount of biocides to a furnace in order to prevent mold building up in the furnace pan.

Is it common in residential buildings, or more common for industrial/commercial?

What kind of biocides are recommended, and what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Furnace? No. You might mean your HVAC condensate pan. Yes, these treatments will help keep the bio slime away and help keep the drain lines clean.

Do an internet search for "condensate pan tablets". Each product will tell you how many tablets to use and how often. They also have treatment mats that you unroll into the pan and they dissolve.